# Start jupyterlab, ignoring my config/startup/kernels

Tags: conda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I want to test what happens if someone creates a fresh conda environment, installs jupyterlab, and tries to open one of my notebooks in jupyterlab.  When I do this (even in a new conda env), it asks me which of 23 different kernels I've accumulated over the years it should start.  I don't want any of that to even appear as an option; I just want what someone would see starting from a fresh install in a fresh home directory.  Is there an option I can pass to get this behavior?  The CLI help text doesn't tell me anything.

Bonus question: One of the options is "Python 3 (ipykernel)".  I don't know where this kernel is coming from.  Is it maybe just some sane default that uses whatever `python` started jupyterlab?  Is there some way to get such a default?